# How to make a UITableViewCell utility buttons fill the whole row?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to remove the white part after the swiping a UITableViewCell? This white part to the left of gray "Share" button.

[image]

Comment: That's the right end of the cell. Why do you want it removed? What do you want in its place?

Comment: If you can, change the width of each action to be the (cell width) / (number of buttons)

Comment: rmaddy, I know, but I want to fill the whole row with utility buttons after swiping. TheSD, I can't. There will be always this white part to be able to swipe cell back, but I don't need that.